# Plotting with GroupBy in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Although it is straight-forward and easy to plot groupby objects in pandas, I am wondering what the most pythonic (pandastic?) way to grab the unique groups from a groupby object is. For example:
  I am working with atmospheric data and trying to plot diurnal trends over a period of several days or more. The following is the DataFrame containing many days worth of data where the timestamp is the index:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 10909 entries, 2013-08-04 12:01:00 to 2013-08-13 17:43:00
Data columns (total 17 columns):
Date     10909  non-null values
Flags    10909  non-null values
Time     10909  non-null values
convt    10909  non-null values
hino     10909  non-null values
hinox    10909  non-null values
intt     10909  non-null values
no       10909  non-null values
nox      10909  non-null values
ozonf    10909  non-null values
pmtt     10909  non-null values
pmtv     10909  non-null values
pres     10909  non-null values
rctt     10909  non-null values
smplf    10909  non-null values
stamp    10909  non-null values
no2      10909  non-null values
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(11), int64(2), object(3)
```

To be able to average (and take other statistics) the data at every minute for several days, I group the dataframe:
    `data = no.groupby('Time')`

I can then easily plot the mean NO concentration as well as quartiles:

```
ax = figure(figsize=(12,8)).add_subplot(111)
title('Diurnal Profile for NO, NO2, and NOx: East St. Louis Air Quality Study')
ylabel('Concentration [ppb]')
data.no.mean().plot(ax=ax, style='b', label='Mean')
data.no.apply(lambda x: percentile(x, 25)).plot(ax=ax, style='r', label='25%')
data.no.apply(lambda x: percentile(x, 75)).plot(ax=ax, style='r', label='75%')
```

The issue that fuels my question, is that in order to plot more interesting looking things like plots using like `fill_between()` it is necessary to know the x-axis information per the documentation

```
fill_between(x, y1, y2=0, where=None, interpolate=False, hold=None, **kwargs)
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out the best way to accomplish this. I have tried:

1. Iterating over the groupby object and creating an array of the groups
2. Grabbing all of the unique Time entries from the original DataFrame

I can make these work, but I know there is a better way. Python is far too beautiful. Any ideas/hints?

***UPDATES:***
The statistics can be dumped into a new dataframe using `unstack()` such as

```
no_new = no.groupby('Time')['no'].describe().unstack()
no_new.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 1440 entries, 00:00 to 23:59
Data columns (total 8 columns):
count    1440  non-null values
mean     1440  non-null values
std      1440  non-null values
min      1440  non-null values
25%      1440  non-null values
50%      1440  non-null values
75%      1440  non-null values
max      1440  non-null values
dtypes: float64(8)
```

Although I should be able to plot with `fill_between()` using `no_new.index`, I receive a `TypeError`.

Current Plot code and `TypeError`:

```
ax = figure(figzise=(12,8)).add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(no_new['mean'])
ax.fill_between(no_new.index, no_new['mean'], no_new['75%'], alpha=.5, facecolor='green')
```

TypeError:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-47493de920f1> in <module>()
      2 ax = figure(figsize=(12,8)).add_subplot(111)
      3 ax.plot(no_new['mean'])
----> 4 ax.fill_between(no_new.index, no_new['mean'], no_new['75%'], alpha=.5,     facecolor='green')
      5 #title('Diurnal Profile for NO, NO2, and NOx: East St. Louis Air Quality Study')
      6 #ylabel('Concentration [ppb]')

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.pyc in fill_between(self, x, y1, y2, where, interpolate, **kwargs)
   6986 
   6987         # Convert the arrays so we can work with them
-> 6988         x = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_xunits(x))
   6989         y1 = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_yunits(y1))
   6990         y2 = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_yunits(y2))

C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.pyc in masked_invalid(a, copy)
   2237         cls = type(a)
   2238     else:
-> 2239         condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))
   2240         cls = MaskedArray
   2241     result = a.view(cls)

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

The plot as of now looks like this:[image]

Comment: Heck that looks pretty good to me... ahh now I think I see,, you need to assign the graph object to a variable then you can grab the axis...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Storing the groupby stats (mean/25/75) as columns in a new dataframe and then passing the new dataframe's `index` as the `x` parameter of `plt.fill_between()` works for me (tested with matplotlib 1.3.1).  e.g.,

```
gdf = df.groupby('Time')[col].describe().unstack()
plt.fill_between(gdf.index, gdf['25%'], gdf['75%'], alpha=.5)
```

`gdf.info()` should look like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 12 entries, 00:00:00 to 22:00:00
Data columns (total 8 columns):
count    12 non-null float64
mean     12 non-null float64
std      12 non-null float64
min      12 non-null float64
25%      12 non-null float64
50%      12 non-null float64
75%      12 non-null float64
max      12 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(8)
```

Update: to address the `TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported` exception, it is necessary to first convert the `Time` column from a series of string objects in "HH:MM" format to a series of `datetime.time` objects, which can be done as follows:

```
df['Time'] = df.Time.map(lambda x: pd.datetools.parse(x).time())
```

Comment: Awesome! This is a great start. I keep receiving a Type Error when trying to fill_between(). It looks like it is having trouble converting the x-axis values? A quick google revealed that this was an error in matplotlib v. 1.3.0, so I upgraded to 1.3.1 but no dice. Any ideas? The exact error is: TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? I think I tested on 0.12 and master

Comment: Stats: Pandas (0.12.0), Numpy (1.8.0), Python (2.7.3 64bit)

Comment: I can't seem to repro that exception.  Would you be able to update the question with a reproducible example?

Comment: Could it be possible that it is just having trouble parsing the format of the x-axis? I tried plotting the mean using no_new.index as the x-axis data and it raised a ValueError for 23:59.

Comment: With the additional info, I think it shows that you need to convert the `Time` column from a series of string objects to a series of `datetime.time` objects.

Comment: try: `no['Time'] = no.Time.map(lambda x: pd.datetools.parse(x).time())`